# What is asking me with "Marque la sílaba tónica"?

Tags: español-neutral, sílabas

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what it wants me to write for the question on "Marque la sílaba tónica?"

Also, what's the difference between **ah**, **ha**, **a**, and **hay**?

Comment: I think you would learn more if you told us what you _think_ the difference between ah, ha, a, hay and so on is then we can help you clarify any misunderstanding

Comment: I think... a is for when you are going somewhere

Comment: ah is when you are surprised about something

Comment: ha is...it's hard for me to try to explain it but I think it means when you're asking for something like "ah visto este programa"

Comment: And ay... ay gets me confused with ah because I look at them as if they were the same thing.

Comment: Please edit your question quoting the text from the image you attach. It will be easier for everyone to understand what you are asking for and, even more important, it will be easier to find in the future.

Comment: Also, do not ask two things in the same question: please split this one into two. Note asking here is free, so there is no problem in posting multiple questions : )

Answer (score 3):

*Marque la sílaba tónica* means you need to mark where the word is correctly stressed. Namely, ***á***nimo, a**ni**mo, ani**mó** are all different and the *sílaba tónica* is bolded to show the correct stress.

Regarding your other question, briefly:

1. *ah* shows *realisation about something*: *ah,* now I get it. (It's the same in English.)
2. *ha* is the auxiliary verb for the third person **present perfect** form: él *ha* trabajado.
3. *a* is a preposition.
4. *hay* is the equivalent for the English *there is/are*.
5. *¡ay!* is for sudden actions: *¡ay!* ¡Me duele!
6. *ahí* is the equivalent for the English *there.*

Comment: Thank you! Also, I just one one more question. How would you divide "Mariana" into syllabuses? Would it be "Ma-ri-a-na" or would it be "Ma-ria-na" and would the "sílaba tónica" be on the "ri" or "a" ? I'm not sure...

Comment: @user152099 ma-**ria**-na and the bold syllabe is the *tónica* one.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry i'm bothering you so much but just to make sure...This is what I have so far for that

Comment: Sorry i'm bothering you so much but just to make sure. This is what I have for my answers so far..: 1) Ma-**ria**-na llana 2) Ex-**pli**-ca-se-lo, subesdrujula 3) bue-**ni**-si-mo, esdrujula 4) mo-nu-**men**-to, llana 5) ja-po-**nes**, aguda 6) im-por-**tan**-te, llana 7) di-**vier**-te, llana 8) re-**pu**-bli-ca, esdrujula

Comment: To come up with the syllabuses just look for the natural pauses as if you were sort of chanting. The would be ma-ri-a-na, Strong vowels (a, e, o) always form their own syllables:

Comment: _¡Ay!_ can also be used to express sorrow for something that has happened before. For instance: _Quise darle la noticia, pero ¡ay!, llegué demasiado tarde._ In this case, it is the equivalent to the English _Alas!_